# Reset Search Index in Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2013

I have corrupted indexes in my Exchange 2013 server and I have having trouble figuring out how to reset them.

I found information on how to do it here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633475.aspx

They tell me this: "If the mailbox database copy is the only copy, Exchange Search must create a new content index catalog. You can use the ResetSearchIndex.ps1 script to do this."

It is in fact the only copy and so I have to use this option, the problem is that they don't give any information on how to run it because it will not run in Powershell. Other articles about 2010 show that I need to go to the scripts directory and run it from there, however this script is not in my script directory on my Exchange 2013 server.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ResetSearchIndex.ps1 script does not exist in 2013 so you have to do it manually. Instead of deleting the folder containing the index files (the one with the long GUID), you can rename it (after stopping the HostControllerService). When you restart the service it will create a new folder.

You can run the command:

```
    Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Server <servername>| FL Name,*Index*
```

to see the status of the indexes BUT be patient as it may take a few minutes for the system to show the index crawling is active again.

I have done this on 2 mailbox databases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the official method is yet, but you can do what the ResetSearchIndex.ps1 script did in 2010, but manually (you'll have to modify the path to the folder in your mailbox database directory).

```
Stop-Service HostControllerService
del -recurse .\Mailbox\Mailbox Database 000000000\E129CBD0-0000-0000-0000-5BAF5C00009312.1.Single
Start-Service HostControllerService
```

Shortly after starting the service back up, the folder returns with updated contents.