# Exchange 2013 has stopped indexing mail on a specific date

Tags: email-server, windows-server-2012, exchange-2013, indexing

A problem has recently occured where no ones mail is being indexed any more. Everyone can search their mail up until early December and then it just stopped.

When you go to the Indexing options on someones Outlook it recognises there are messages to be indexed as everything is still being received correctly but it refuses to budge.

This happens on both the web app and Outlook itself and I just don't know exchange well enough to diagnose the problem so anything that may point me in the right direction would help as i have seen this question: [Reset Search Index in Exchange 2013](https://serverfault.com/questions/487124/reset-search-index-in-exchange-2013) but am unsure if it applies.

Running Exchange 2013 + Windows Server 2012 Datacenter

So far:

- Checked Index status with Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Server | FL Name,*Index*
- Mailbox database Index was corrupted, others saying Reseeding required
- Stopped Search Host and Search Services
- Renamed folder, restarted services
- Mailbox status "Healthly" but others still on reseeding required
- Indexing seems to have got stuck around a particular date, namely, early December, and it doesn't seem to be crawling anymore
- Mailbox now shows Failed: Internal error has occured For the Database or Index

I just had a quick dig through some files an old technician moved before Christmas and I've possibly found something. Space on the server was low and they moved some of the .log files you find in the Mailbox folders as well as some of the database (.edp) files. Though I assume if we were actually using them we wouldn't be able to see the mail either but I wonder if it has something to do with it, because there's definitely some missing .log files.

Edit..(I've lost count) : The other databases are in use, it seems they were moved and they're still updating on the other drive, found the index folders for them (not in the normal hieracrchy) and working on reseeding those now with above solution.

**Final Edit: Problem solved, answer is to make sure you check where all your DB's are and follow the procedure outlined in this question [Reset Search Index in Exchange 2013](https://serverfault.com/questions/487124/reset-search-index-in-exchange-2013)**

Comment: Yes, you should follow that question.  You can look through the Application Log on the Exchange server for Index errors as well beforehand, but that linked question is where I would head down if you are seeing this in OWA as well.

Comment: From the EMS run "Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus" and "Test-ExchangeSearch" and post the results here.

Comment: Updated my question with results. It's only indexed up to about the 3rd December and seems to have stopped. Mailbox database states healthy where as the others state reseeding required.